# Embedding of an open subset

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

How can one embedd an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with a closed map? Can one make that embedding smooth? I had some idea like $F \colon V \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ given by $F(x)=(x,dist(x,\partial V))$. But I don't know how to show if the map is closed.

Comment: You know that the inclusion, $i (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0)$ is a closed map, right?

Comment: @JohnHughes It's not going to be closed when restricted to $V$.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the question that the map's domain was to be $V$. But you're certainly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't address the smoothness issue, but following your suggestion (with altered notation) I'll use the function
$$x \mapsto \left(x,\frac{1}{d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-V)}\right)
$$
where $d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-V)$ denotes the infimum of $d(x,y)$ over all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n-V$.

The fact that this map is closed follows by applying continuity of the function $x \mapsto d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-V)$. To see this, consider a sequence $(x_i,\frac{1}{d(x_i,\mathbb{R}^n-V)})$ in the image that converges to a limit $(x,a) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The sequence $x_i$ in the domain $V$ converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $x \in V$ then by applying continuity we get $d(x,\mathbb{R}-V)=\frac{1}{a}$ and you're done. If $x \in \mathbb{R}-V$ then $d(x_i,\mathbb{R}^n-V)$ converges to zero, but this contradicts that $\frac{1}{d(x_i,\mathbb{R}^n-V)}$ converges to $a$.

Comment: Oops, yes, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Lee for an elegant solution.  Now it is clear to me to me why to use $\frac{1}{dist(\cdot,\mathbb R^n \setminus V)}$ and why openness of $V$ plays a role. The smoothness is much harder, or do you feel like there is no such a map?

Comment: I think probably existence of a smooth embedding is true, because I think that the function $d(\cdot,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus V)$ can be approximated by a smooth function with an error that goes to zero much faster than the function itself approaches zero. One would have to check a differential topology book, my first choice probably being the book by Hirsch.